# Swagger not showing up documentation for each element

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger

I'm using Swagger to generate documentation for Apache CXF RESTful API. I'm having xsd and DTOs are generated from xsd using xjc plugin.I want swagger to show up the documentation of each element from xsd under Response Class - Model section of swagger.

I don't have control on the generated DTOs as it's shared across multiple project. I can't annotate the DTO object with swagger annotation as suggested in some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I had a Similar issues. When I tried to swagger a resource that returned a response.ok(STRING).build(): 
I had the method annotated:

```
 @ApiOperation(value = "Something Resource", notes = "Support for Resource", response = String.class)
```

And that hosed my swaggered output. I ended up removing it and all was well. I'm not sure exactly why, but if I was you I would just comment out a few ApiOpertions & ApiResponse until it shows correctly.

Good Luck sir!